# Run AutoML_execution failed with exception - Azure ML Studio JupyterLab

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I was trying to do a time series experiment as per this article - [Auto-train a time-series forecast model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/machine-learning/how-to-auto-train-forecast)

At first run, I was using the following code block.

```
time_series_settings = {
"time_column_name": "day_datetime",
"grain_column_names": ["store"],
"max_horizon": "auto",
"target_lags": "auto",
"target_rolling_window_size": "auto",
"preprocess": True,
```

}

Then, I decided to push it to limits. started changing the horizon to higher units. I ran into a limit based on the training data, which was fine. I simply had to use a lower horizon value. Then, that error stopped and I started getting an error of this format.

```
Run AutoML_6f4dff67-59e2-46b3-ba56-54f35d3813a6_27 failed with exception
```

I thought, it was an issue with the VM size, so I switched back to the default values, from the original notebook which ran successfully half an hour ago. that also had stopped working.

So, what to do? That error wont go away.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a bug or a normal issue with JupyterLab running on Azure in general, but a complete compute engine restart fixed the problem.

I was able to push the horizon as high as it would go, without running into that error.

*Solution : Restart your Azure ML Studio Compute Engine at ml.azure.com, in your main workspace. save your work before doing that.*